# Holomorphic function in an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to do a question but I have a doubt on holomorphic functions, here is the problem.

> Let $A = \{z ∈ \mathbb{C} : \frac{1}{R}< |z| < R\}$. Suppose that $f : A → \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and
>   that $|f(z)| = 1 $ if $|z| = 1$. 
>   Show that $f(z) = {\left(\overline{f(\bar{z}^{−1})}\right)}^{-1}$ when $ |z| = 1 $ and deduce that this holds for all $z ∈ A$.

Now, my problem is with the final deduction...

I think I need something about the zeroes of f as the right-hand side of the equality could not be defined at some point. 
Am I right or is there a way to prove that a function with these properties can never be zero in A?

Thank you all.

Comment: p.s. knowing that it is never zero i think the most is done as the rhs is holomorphic as well and you just use the uniqueness theorem as |z|=1 has a limit point in A

Comment: If $|z|=1$ then $(\bar z)^{—1}=z$.

Comment: Max. modulus principle gives me an upper bound for the modulus of the function doesn't it? What I need is a lower (positive) bound..
I'm not even sure if it is true that such a function has to be non zero, a mobius transformation which maps the unit circle to itself can actually have zeros...

Comment: i think it is true, actually it must be by the uniqueness theorem!

Comment: Yes, you don't need to prove it doesn't have any zeroes, it follows from the uniqueness theorem.

Comment: but for the uniqueness theorem i need the function on the rhs to be holomorphic in A. and it is not if f has zeroes in A, that's why I am worried about them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(z) \cdot \overline{f(1/\,\overline{z})}$ is well-defined and holomorphic on $A$ and equal to $1$ for $|z|=1$.  Then it is constant on $A$, since level sets of non-constant holomorphic functions are discrete.

Comment: thank you, really helpful! I couldn't see the last part so easily (don't really understand the terminology)
anyway I did get it using identity theorem!